# The system cannot find the file specified - WinError 2

Tags: python-3.x

Upon looping a directory to delete `txt` files ONLY  - a message is returned indicating The System cannot find the file specified: 'File.txt'.

I've made sure the `txt` files that I'm attempting to delete exist in the directory I'm looping. I've also checked my code and to make sure it can see my files by printing them in a list with the print command.

```
import os
fileLoc = 'c:\\temp\\files'
for files in os.listdir(fileLoc):
    if files.endswith('.txt'):
        os.unlink(files)
```

Upon initial execution, I expected to see all txt files deleted except for other non-txt files. The actual result was an error message `"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'File.txt'.`
Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't found because the the path you intended to `unlink` is relative to `fileLoc`.  In fact with your code, the effect is to `unlink` the file relative to the current working directory.  If there were `*.txt` files
in the cwd then the code would have unfortunate side-effects.

Another way to look at it:

Essentially, by analogy, in the shell what you're trying to do is equivalent to this:

```
# first the setup
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/a.txt

# now your code is equvalent to:
$ rm *.txt

# won't work as intended because it removes the *.txt files in the
# current directory.  In fact the bug is also that your code would unlink
# any *.txt files in the current working directory unintentionally.

# what you intended was:
$ rm foo/*.txt
```

The missing piece was the **path to the file** in question.

I'll add some editorial:  The Old Bard taught us to "when in doubt, print variables".  In other words, debug it.  I don't see from the OP an attempt to do that.  Just a thing to keep in mind.

Anyway the new code:

Revised:

```
import os
fileLoc = 'c:\\temp\\files'
for file in os.listdir(fileLoc):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        os.unlink(os.path.join(fileLoc,file))
```

The fix:  `os.path.join()` builds a path for you from parts.  One part is the directory (path) where the file exists, aka: `fileLoc`.  The other part is the filename, aka `file`.

`os.path.join()` makes a whole valid path from them using whatever OS directory separator is appropriate for your platform.

Also, might want to glance through:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html